# Is there any ways to manipulate Facebook page plugin using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, iframe

I am using Facebook page plugin on my website. The problem with the FB page plugin is the responsiveness. Even after trying out several hacks suggested here, I could not able to achieve the responsiveness.

I see inside the generated iframe, an element with fixed width of 360px. I am trying to edit them using jQuery it throws the following error.

```
VM30148 OoiHgnWq65g.js:41 Uncaught Error: <![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it is not present on the page.","._2p3a"]]]>
    at h (VM30148 OoiHgnWq65g.js:41)
    at i (VM30148 OoiHgnWq65g.js:41)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

The element is:

```
<div class="_2p3a" style="min-width: 180px; width: 333px;">
```

Any suggestion of removing the style attribute of the element inside the iFrame?

Comment: You are trying to get `ID` but that element doesn't have it. It has `class` -
 `_2p3a`

Comment: _"removing the style attribute of the element inside the iFrame"_ no, thanks to cross-origin restrictions.

Comment: OK @evoltionxbox. Is there any ways I could edit the style attribute?

Comment: @mxr7350 The element does not have an ID attribute.